# pdf file is not saving/creating in internal

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a pdf in internal memory with this code but i couldn't create a pdf file because of some unknown reasons i have android 11 there are no errors in logcat toast is showing success please help me with the code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button create_btn;
    File file;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        create_btn = findViewById(R.id.create_btn);


        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        createPDF();

    }

    private void createPDF() {
        create_btn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            PdfDocument myPdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
            Paint myPaint = new Paint();
            PdfDocument.PageInfo myPageInfo1 = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(250, 400, 1)
                    .create();
            PdfDocument.Page myPage1 = myPdfDocument.startPage(myPageInfo1);
            Canvas canvas = myPage1.getCanvas();
            canvas.drawText("Expert Laptops", 40, 50, myPaint);
            myPdfDocument.finishPage(myPage1);

            file = new File(MainActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir("/"), "firstPDF.pdf");

            try {
                myPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sucessfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unsucessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            myPdfDocument.close();

        });
    }
}

Android Manifest

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true".../>
```

Thankyou

Comment: How did you check if the file is there,?

Comment: The things in manifest are not needed for that storage location

Comment: I opened file manager and check in external storage where it should be created and search my whole file manager with the pdf name

Comment: `where it should be created` Indeed no file manager kan display your a `file = new File(MainActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir("/"), "firstPDF.pdf");`. DId you have a look at the value of `file.getAbsolutePath()` ? Thats tells you the path to your file. Now find out the path and then try again with file managers and then tell us how deep you can enter that directory path.

Comment: Thanks blackapps your suggestion gave me an idea so i played with the code little and give it a path where i can easily find my pdf

Comment: Blackapps can you help me with one more tiny problem. I am using mac air 2017 osx version 11.5(big sur) 8gb ram 128ssd. While writing code android studio takes all my cpu usage so work become choppy and laptop starts lagging. Not able to fix it tried all the solutions on the internet, according to android studio activity monitor jit compiler is taking all the usage while typing. do you have any solution for this???